# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am trying to implement a Sceduled Job in scala play framework.

Following is my code:

```
def subCron = {

val task = new Runnable {
  def run() = {
    writingToFile(s"Name,Job,M,Age\n", "Media1", "FileName")
  }
}

val pool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

val schedule = pool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
schedule.cancel(false)

}
```

Basic idea is to write a file after a specific interval. I am using `writingToFile` function in my `run`, but it seems that the code does not execute when I call the function.

Please suggest on how to make it work.

Comment: @ZbyszekKr Thank you for your review

Comment: Right after you schedule your task you are canceling it. So why the code should be executed? Also Akka already does that

Comment: Thank you very much @Salem for clarification. Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheduled task is being canceled right after it is defined, so it will not run.

Apart from that, Akka (which already comes with Play) also supports scheduling tasks.

```scala
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
// Delete a file after 10 seconds
val cancellable = system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) {
  file.delete()
}

// Print the message "Hi" every 30 seconds, starting after 5 seconds 
val cancellable = system.scheduler.schedule(5.seconds, 300.seconds) {
  log("Hi")
}
```

Examples adapted from: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks